# Pick files with certain file names in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a folder with around 200,000 jpeg images. Below are the format of fileNames I can find

1. BATCHID_GROUPID ex: 501234_20123.jpg
2. BATCHID_GROUPID ex. 501235_20124_1.jpg, 501235_20124_2.jpg, 501235_20124_3.jpg. Each of this type images will have max of 10 images of BATCHID_GROUPID. What I mean is for this set the max will be 501235_20124_10.jpg

I need to take all the images that don't end with _x or _xx i.e _1.jpg or _2.jpg or _10.jpg and pick the BATCHID and copy it and FTP it to a different location

For the ones that end with _x or _xx I need to pick BATCHID and create a folder with the name as batchID and move all the files that end with _X to _xx into the folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on your files names, check for length to determine where you are going to copy it and take the first index as your BATCHID:

Something like this:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("SourcePath");
IEnumerable<FileInfo> fileinfo = di.EnumerateFiles();
foreach(FileInfo fi in fileinfo)
{
    string[] tmp = fi.Name.Split('_');
    if (tmp.Length == 3)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists("YourPath"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("YourPath" + tmp[0].ToString());
            fi.MoveTo("YourPath" + tmp[0].ToString() + @"\" + fi.Name);

        }
        else
            fi.MoveTo("YourPath" + + tmp[0].ToString() + @"\" + fi.Name);

    }
    else if (tmp.Length == 2)
    {
        //Copy Batch Id and Ftp logic
    }
}
```